# Why there are no definite articles in the other two phrases?

Tags: articles

The definite articles in brackets are added by me, not from the original article. I wonder why there are no definite articles, like the other two in bold in the same sentence, at here? The four phrases are all looked the same to me.

Thanks!

---

> Vitamin D contributes to the regulation of the immune system through
>   multiple mechanisms, including (**the**) regulation of the activation and
>   differentiation of CD4 lymphocytes, **the** suppression of differentiation
>   of monocytes into dendritic cells, **the** reduction of cytokine
>   production, and (**the**) stimulation of natural killer T cells (38).

source:[Immunopathogenesis in Myasthenia Gravis and Neuromyelitis Optica.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5732908/#S4title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definite articles are not right or wrong there.  They are absent because these things are being presented *generically*.  They are sub-headings, as it were, beneath the topic "immune system regulatory mechanisms". Furthermore, they are defined by the prepositional phrases that follow them.